# How do I check if a character is a in a string?

Tags: c++, c++11

The situation is like this, I don't have to know where the character is, but only if it is there. And I am looking for a fast solution, possibly integrated. Thanks in advance!

I am using c++11.

Answer (score 0):

The following function will stop looking for the character as soon as it finds one:

```
std::string str ("My string with: a");

if (str.find_first_of("a")!=std::string::npos)
{
    return 1;
}
else
{
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you mean standard class `std::string` then it has method find

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

//...

std::string s( "123456789" );

auto n = s.find( '5' );

if ( n != std::string::npos )
{ 
    std::cout << "character '5' found at position " << n << std::endl;
}
```

You could write a function using this method. For example

```
bool find_char( const std::string &s, char c )
{
    return ( s.find( c ) != std::string::npos );
}
```

If you want that the function would return either 1 or 0 then simply change its return type to int.

```
int find_char( const std::string &s, char c )
{
    return ( s.find( c ) != std::string::npos );
}
```

If you mean character arrays then you can use either standard algorithms `std::find` or `std::any_of` or standard C function `strchr`

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

//...

char s[] = "123456789";

char *p = std::strchr( s, '5' );


if ( p != nullptr ) 
{
    std::cout << "character '5' found at position " << p - s << std::endl;
}
```

Or if to use algorithm `std::find` then the code will look like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

//...

char s[] = "123456789";

char *p = std::find( std::begin( s ), std::end( s ), '5' );

if ( p != std::end( s ) )
{
    std::cout << "character '5' found at position " << std::distance( s, p ) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I have already seen find. The problem is I want it to return 1 if the char exists or 0 if it doesn't.

Comment: @rebel1234 That's not a problem

Comment: @rebel1234  In this case you can simply wrap the call of the method in a function that will retrun either true or false.